Using SeleniumBase UC MODE, a button is not clickable anyhow
I love the SeleniumBase system. It work's smooth. Bur right now I am facing the problem while taking the Xpath of a button, it's not clicked anyhow!
Here is the full element of that button, strong text
<button mat-raised-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator btn mat-btn-lg btn-block btn-brand-orange mat-raised-button mat-button-base"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"> Start New Booking </span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>

Please let me know, How it can be clickable.
Thanks
I am trying to make the button clickabe using sb.click() method. Here in this particular task, I am using UC mode to avoide captcha issue
Note: this is the only button of that page and When I able to click on it , it should navigate to another page.

Have you tried using sb.js_click(selector) to click that button? For js_click, pass in a CSS Selector.

Yes, I did, but still didn't worked. It says""" seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
Element {mat-raised-button} was not present after 30 seconds!""

That's not the correct selector. button[mat-raised-button] is the selector. mat-raised-button is just an attribute of a selector.
